# How to print javascript value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

To make a long story short, I am setting up a simplecart(JS) and for multiple options I am using checkboxes. 
Everything works fine calculating the different options in the cart, exept I need to print the text "VAT 21% €90" or "World (Taxfree)" (depending on what has been checked) in #tax div.
How can I do this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
simpleCart.tax = function(){
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "VAT 21% €90" ){return 90;}
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "World (Taxfree)" ){return 0;}
};
</script>


  <input type="checkbox" name="tax" id="regionSelect" class="item_tax" value="eu" onClick="">Eu VAT 21%
  <input type="checkbox" name="tax" id="regionSelect" class="item_tax" value="world"onClick="">World (Tax Free)   
  </dd>


<div id="tax"></div
```

**UPDATE**

Where exactly do I add this?

This only works for the later one.

```
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "eu" ){return 90;} $("#tax").html("VAT 21% €90")
    if( $("#regionSelect").val() == "world" ){return 0;} $("#tax").html("World (Taxfree)")
```

Comment: In reply to your update, no not quite. See my answer. You should have your `html` functions _inside_ your if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#regionSelect").val()` will never equal `VAT 21% ?90` or `World (Taxfree)` because you set the value of the `input` element in html to `eu` and `world`. What comes after the input of checkbox is not the value, just some random text that jquery will not read. Therefore, it should change to `$("#regionSelect").val() == "eu"` or `$("#regionSelect").val() == "world"` respectively.

Additionally, `id`s should be unique, and not duplicated. That's what `class`es are for. As mentioned above, the jQuery `html()` and `text()` functions are the way to go for printing text to elements.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
simpleCart.tax = function(){
    if( $(".regionSelect").val() == "eu" ){return 90; $("#tax").html("EU VAT 21%");}
    if( $(".regionSelect").val() == "world" ){return 0; $("#tax").html("World (Taxfree)");}
};
</script>


<input type="checkbox" name="tax" class="item_tax regionSelect" value="eu" onClick="">Eu VAT 21%
<input type="checkbox" name="tax" class="item_tax regionSelect" value="world"onClick="">World (Tax Free)   
</dd>


<div id="tax"></div>
```

And also, you have a closing `dd` element? I'm assuming you also have an opening one as well. Otherwise that could also create problems.

Comment: Yes dd is in order.. thank you so much, I guess I have been awake to long to finish this one :)

Comment: uups my bad.. now the value of 0 or 90 is not added to the cart

Comment: This may be because I removed the `id` of `regionSelect` and made it a `class`. Your back end cart could be set to look for `#regionSelect`. You could also try putting the `return` statement _after_ the `$("#tax").html(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function like as below.

```
$("#divid").html("World (Taxfree)")
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the div you want to add the text to. And then add it with jquery's `.text()` function.

```
$("#divtoget").text("text to set")
```